# Date cannot be within x working days of today

Tags: formula, validation

I need a validation rule that checks the date of a field is not within 4 working days of today's date. Is it possible to do this, what would the formula look like?

Comment: There are lots and lots of formula field examples around the internet for calculating number of business days between two dates/number of business days in advance on Salesforce. Did you try any of these yet? Quickly Googling I found 3 blog posts that would sort you out quite quickly, but I didn't want to just re-post them as an answer on here.

Comment: If your definition of "working day" is Mon-Fri then +1 for Simon's answer. If you want to reference the platform's business hours (that takes account of holidays too) then you have to resort to Apex code via triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you'd need to combine these two validation rules:

```
My_Date__c - TODAY() > 4
```

and

```
CASE(MOD( My_Date__c - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7),
0, 0,
6, 0,
1) = 0
```

The first obviously gives you a date that's more than 4 days from today. The 2nd gives you weekdays since the start of the year 1900. You might need to first check to see which day of the week it was, then change your criteria for `My_Date__c - TODAY() > 4` to `My_Date__c - TODAY() > 5 or 6` if its either a Tuesday or Wednesday.

I don't know if TODAY() is allowed to be a Sat or Sun, but clearly, `My_Date__c - TODAY() > 4` works for that condition, so the main thing you need to check for is if TODAY() is a Tues or Wed then adjust accordingly.